# Pass class type as a function parameter and use as? to cast the class

Tags: swift, type-inference

Is there a way do pass a class type via a function and try to convert a class to the given class type? I have tried the following code.

```
class Section {}
class TimeSection: Section {}
class TaskSection: Section {}

let timeSection = TimeSection()
let taskSection = TaskSection()

let sections = [timeSection, taskSection]

func findSection(from classType: Section.Type) {
    for section in sections {
        guard let section = section as? classType else { continue }

        print("Found section")
    }
}

findSection(from: TimeSection.self)
```

But I always get this error:

```
Use of undeclared type 'classType'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Swift 4.2

You can use a generic function and restrict the type parameter to be a Section.

```
import Foundation

class Section {}
class TimeSection: Section {}
class TaskSection: Section {}
class NoSection {}

let timeSection = TimeSection()
let taskSection = TaskSection()

let sections = [timeSection, taskSection]

func findSection<T: Section>(from classType: T.Type) {
    for section in sections {
        guard let section = section as? T else { continue }

        print("Found section: \(section)")
    }
}

findSection(from: TimeSection.self) // Found section: __lldb_expr_9.TimeSection
findSection(from: TaskSection.self) // Found section: __lldb_expr_9.TaskSection
findSection(from: NoSection.self) // won't compile
```

Answer (score 0):

`classType` is not actually a type. It is a parameter that holds an instance of `Section.Type`. Therefore, you cannot use it with `as?`.

Since it is a parameter, you can compare it with `==`. The other side of `==` should be an instance of the metatype of `section`, which can be acquired by `type(of:)`.

```
func findSection(from classType: Section.Type) {
    for section in sections {
        if type(of: section) == classType {
            print("Found section")
            break
        }
    }
}
```